# Overleaf.com keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: overleaf

Does anyone know any useful [Overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com) shortcuts? I have been using Overleaf for about a month and so far it has been great to be able to work on documents on any computer.

I have stumbled across a few keyboard shortcuts

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>/</kbd>  Comment a block of text
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>,</kbd>  Finds page from source code
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>.</kbd>  Refresh preview
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Z</kbd>  Undo
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd>  Bold
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>I</kbd>  Italics

Perhaps the last three shouldn't surprise me but useful to know it's there. I haven't seen a page on the website that lists the available shortcuts so I'm wondering if anyone has come across any others?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes -- a list is now available here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qykqfvmxdnjf

It'll be updated if more shortcuts are added.

Comment: Please...make Overleaf support Vim Latex-suite...it boosts so much efficiency.

Comment: @TroyWoo Have you seen https://www.overleaf.com/blog/19 ? Note though that CodeMirror (the editor on Overleaf) doesn't support all vim commands: https://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I was not referring to the original VIM shortcuts, but the vim latex suite shortcuts. Please take a look at this http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/. Do you have something similar for overleaf?

Comment: @TroyWoo I'm afraid not, sorry. You can send a feature request to Overleaf, so that it's recorded for future consideration — thanks!

Comment: This list is incomplete: at least in vim keybindings, :w<enter> is the same as <control><enter> and it compiles. I wonder if there is any keybinding to show the filetree (left panel).

Comment: @imnothere I forgot to notify you.

Answer (score 17):

You can also click on <kbd>F1</kbd> in Overleaf, and it'll appear all shortcuts and commands available.

[image]

---

Note: Many shortcuts don't work properly in "Rich Text" mode. So, first, switch to "Source" mode.

Comment: Thank you! Despite what the other answer said, the shortcuts on that page are not a complete list. This is the way to see all the **currently** available shortcuts.

Comment: Yes! Awesome. I asked this question originally but have been away from LaTeX and overleaf for almost a year now. With everything that's happening(school closings) I may be using overleaf a lot more. I've got some catching up to do. They've upgraded so much since the v1 editor.

Comment: my F1 key takes me to the windows 10 help page-how can i get around this

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to `Menu` on the top-left and scroll down for `Show Hotkeys` to see all the keyboard shortcuts. [image: All keyboard shortcuts on Overleaf]